# Remove Mobile margin

Tags: wordpress

I have website based on wordpress. And I have removed all responsive thing because my image maps and images placing all massed up when responded.
Anyway, My website is now displayed like first image, which has a margin on mobile. To see as second image with no margin, have to zoom in with two fingers. Is there any way to display my website as the second image when just accessing to my web?

First image

[image]

Second image

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: Ah, I missed My website url : http://yoys.kr

Comment: Thank you for suggesting @Syfer